# Junk values in char* variable

Tags: c

Code:

```
char* data = NULL;
data = new char[lengthOfParam];   //lengthOfParam = 3
                               //after allocation **data = ¥¥¥¥Ü\r**
memcpy(data,&buffer[offset],lengthOfParam);   //**data = pki¥Ü\r**
```

Why i am getting that junk values??? How to avoid or remove those extra values bcs if i try to assign that value to any other array 
ex:

```
obj[1] = data;
```

then the whole value with junk'll be assigned to that variable.

Comment: What is `buffer`? What is `lengthOfParam`?

Comment: There is no new operator in C.

Comment: buffer is argument in LVParams(char* buffer,int offset, signed char* codeWord) , lengthOfParam is of type int.

Comment: @poppy Can you please clarify what language you think your code is (C or C++)? Preferably by editing the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings in C need to be NUL terminated. This means you need to add a zero value byte to the end of the string to indicate the end of the string. Because you have no indication of the end of the string when you view/print the value you are reading on past the end of your array into whatever memory is after it.

If the source data contains a NUL terminator you can simply allocate and copy 1 more byte, but assuming it is a fixed length field with no NUL termination you will need to manually add one:

```
data = new char[lengthOfParam+1];

memcpy(data, &buffer[offset], lengthOfParam);
data[lengthOfParam] = 0;
```

Also further more looking at this line you posted:

```
obj[1] = data;
```

I maybe wrong here and sorry if I am but I strongly suspect this line is not doing what you think it is. This will store a pointer to your string in `obj[1]` not copy the data from your string. Hence if you delete `data`, `obj[1]` would no longer be valid either.

Comment: you may be right but when i return obj from this method like this char** LVParams(char* buffer,int offset, signed char* codeWord) Function calling : char** sss = LVParams(arr1, 0, code_word_arr); so here when i check like this i am getting correct values  char *s1 = sss[0];char* s2 = sss[1];

Comment: i tried what you suggested its correct after assigning terminator getting exact values. Thank you Charles Keepax.

Answer (score 1):

Is this C or C++?

In the language containing `new`, you can also do

```
std::string data(&buffer[offset], lengthOfParam);
```

assuming `buffer` is an array of char.

Comment: buffer is of type char* buffer.