# Junk values in C string when printing to stdout and writing to file

Tags: c, arrays, c-strings

I'm playing around with C strings and streams to get a better understanding of them.
I have this test program to read a fixed size block of data from an input file to a buffer, store the buffer contents in an intermediate storage (in this case, I want the storage to be able to store three different "reads") and then write the read string and one of the strings in intermediate storage to an output file.

A note on this: In each iteration I just use the two first positions of the intermediate storage and just write the second "stored string" to the file.

**THE CODE:**

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 3
#define BUFFER_SIZE 5

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  FILE* local_stream_test = fopen("LOCAL_INPUT_FILE","r");
  FILE* local_output_test = fopen("LOCAL_OUTPUT_TEST","w");

  if(!local_stream_test) {
    puts("!INPUT FILE");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  if(!local_output_test) {
    puts("!OUTPUT FILE");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  char my_buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
  char test[SIZE];
  char* test2[SIZE];
  memset(my_buffer,0,sizeof(my_buffer));
  memset(test,0,sizeof(test));
  memset(test2,0,sizeof(test2));

  int read = fread( my_buffer, sizeof(my_buffer[0]), sizeof(my_buffer)/sizeof(my_buffer[0]), local_stream_test );

   printf("FIRST READ TEST: %d\n",read);
   printf("\tMY_BUFFER, SIZEOF: %lu, STRLEN: %lu\n",sizeof(my_buffer),strlen(my_buffer));

   fwrite(my_buffer,sizeof(my_buffer[0]),/*strlen(aux)*/ read,local_output_test);
   char* aux_test = strdup(my_buffer);
   printf("\tAUX_TEST STRLEN: %lu, ## %s\n",strlen(aux_test), aux_test);
   free(aux_test);
   aux_test = NULL;

   while(read > 0) {
     if(feof(local_stream)) {
       puts("BYE");
       break;
     }
     read = fread( my_buffer, sizeof(my_buffer[0]), sizeof(my_buffer)/sizeof(my_buffer[0]), local_stream_test );
     aux_test = strdup(my_buffer);

     if(!aux_test) {
       puts("!AUX_TEST");
       break;
     }


     printf("READ TEST: %d\n",read);
     printf("\tMY_BUFFER, SIZEOF: %lu, STRLEN: %lu\n",sizeof(my_buffer),strlen(my_buffer));
     printf("\tAUX_TEST, SIZEOF: %lu, STRLEN: %lu ** SIZEOF *AUX_TEST: %lu, SIZEOF AUX_TEST[0]: %lu\n",sizeof(aux_test),strlen(aux_test),sizeof(*aux_test),sizeof(aux_test[0]));

     fwrite(aux_test,sizeof(aux[0]),/*strlen(aux)*/ read,local_output_test);

     printf("** AUX_TEST: %s\n",aux_test);
     test2[0] = aux_test;
     test2[1] = aux_test;
     test2[1][3] = toupper(test2[1][3]);

     fwrite(test2[1],sizeof(test2[1][0]),read,local_output_test);

     printf("\n** TEST2[0] SIZEOF: %lu, STRLEN: %lu, TEST2[0]: %s\n",sizeof(test2[0]),strlen(test2[0]),test2[0]);
     printf("\n** TEST2[1] SIZEOF: %lu, STRLEN: %lu, TEST2[1]: %s\n",sizeof(test2[1]),strlen(test2[1]),test2[1]);

     strcpy(test2[1],aux_test);
     printf("** COPIED TEST2[1]: %s\n",test2[1]);
     free(aux_test);
     aux_test = NULL;
     puts("*******************************************");
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**THE INPUT FILE:**

```
converts a byte string to a floating point value
converts a byte string to an integer value
converts a byte string to an integer value
```

When printing the strings I get extra junk values at the end of it after the second read. Here's the output in `stdout` for the first, second and third read's from the file:

```
FIRST READ TEST: 5
    MY_BUFFER, SIZEOF: 5, STRLEN: 5
    AUX_TEST STRLEN: 5, ## conve
READ TEST: 5
    MY_BUFFER, SIZEOF: 5, STRLEN: 5
    AUX_TEST, SIZEOF: 4, STRLEN: 5 ** SIZEOF *AUX_TEST: 1, SIZEOF AUX_TEST[0]: 1

** AUX_TEST: rts a

** TEST2[0] SIZEOF: 4, STRLEN: 5, TEST2[0]: rts a

** TEST2[1] SIZEOF: 4, STRLEN: 5, TEST2[1]: rts a
** COPIED TEST2[1]: rts a

*******************************************
READ TEST: 5
    MY_BUFFER, SIZEOF: 5, STRLEN: 13
    AUX_TEST, SIZEOF: 4, STRLEN: 13 ** SIZEOF *AUX_TEST: 1, SIZEOF AUX_TEST[0]: 1

** AUX_TEST:  byte▒▒▒▒

** TEST2[0] SIZEOF: 4, STRLEN: 13, TEST2[0]:  byTe▒▒▒▒


** TEST2[1] SIZEOF: 4, STRLEN: 13, TEST2[1]:  byTe▒▒▒▒

** COPIED TEST2[1]:  byTe▒▒▒▒
```

What troubles me is the fact that when the junk values start to appear, the length of the string is greater than the read bytes from the file: `13` versus `5`.
I have played around with the `BUFFER_SIZE` but I always get the junk values when printing to `stdout` unless the size is big enough to read the file in one go.

For example, with `BUFFER_SIZE` equals to `500`, this is the output in `stdout`:

```
FIRST READ TEST: 135
    MY_BUFFER, SIZEOF: 300, STRLEN: 135
    AUX_TEST STRLEN: 135, ## converts a byte string to a floating point value
       converts a byte string to an integer value
        converts a byte string to an integer value

 BYE
```

And the output files generated:

**BUFFER_SIZE = 5**

```
converts arts a byte byTe stri stRing tong To a fl a FloatinoatIng poig pOint vant Value
clue
converonvErts a ts A byte bytE strinstrIng to g tO an inan IntegertegEr valu vaLue
cone
cOnvertsverTs a by a Byte stte String rinG to anto An inte inTeger vger value
aluE
```

**BUFFER_SIZE = 500:** The same as the input file.

So, I'm accessing out of bounds memory, right? But, where? I can't find the source of this problem (and most likely I have a misunderstanding in how to work with C strings).

**PS:**

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11650861/junk-values-in-char-variable) that maybe my problem is that I forgot to add the NULL mark at the end of the string. Doing:

```
 test2[0] = aux_test;
 test2[0][ strlen(aux_test)+1 ] = '\0';

 /* OR THIS */
 test2[0][read+1] = '\0';
```

produces the same result.

Comment: Perhaps an informative read: [C pointers are not arrays](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/c-faq/c-2.html), but arrays do decay into pointers

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem, Thank you! I'll read it tonight!

Comment: +1 for an SSCCE with supporting input and output data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part of your problem is that you are reading outside the bounds of your arrays, and `fread()` certainly doesn't null terminate anything.

For example:

```
printf("\tMY_BUFFER, SIZEOF: %lu, STRLEN: %lu\n",sizeof(my_buffer),strlen(my_buffer));
```

You read 5 bytes of data into an array of size 5 bytes.  The `strlen()` reports 5; you were lucky that the first byte beyond the end of the array happened to be a zero byte, but since it was outside the array, you invoked undefined behaviour at that point (even though you got the answer you were expecting).

In the loop, in the first iteration, the `toupper()` case-converts a blank, which doesn't change it.
`test2[0]` and `test2[1]` both point to the same string, so if the `toupper()` did anything, it would affect the value pointed at by both those pointers.

When the junk values 'appear', you've put non-zero bytes into the data after the end of `my_buffer`, and the `strlen()` reads through those non-zero bytes until it reaches a zero byte.  So, the problem is all due to not ensure that your character buffers are null terminated within the allocated length.
When you invoked undefined behaviour, weird stuff can happen.

Note that if you use `printf("<<%.*s>>\n", read, my_buffer);` you will only print the bytes of data that were read.

---

You ask about:

```
test2[0] = aux_test;
test2[0][ strlen(aux_test)+1 ] = '\0';
/* OR THIS */
test2[0][read+1] = '\0';
```

You are accessing one byte beyond the end of what was provided.  By definition, `strlen(str)` returns the first number `len` such that `str[len] == '\0'`.  When you write `test2[0][[strlen(aux_test)+1] = '\0';` therefore, you are writing one byte beyond the end of the first null in the string.  The `test2[0][read+1] = '\0';` assignment, assuming you've just read 5 bytes, overwrites `test2[0][6]`, but the last byte of data that was read is in `test2[0][4]`, so you've not changed `test2[0][5]` (and it isn't clear whether you're allowed to).

```
test2[0][strlen(aux_test)] = '\0';  // No-op, but safe
test2[0][read] = '\0';              // If you left enough space, null terminates the input
```

Comment: `and fread() certainly doesn't null terminate anything` Ok. I thought `fread` took care of the null byte. So for example, a solution would be to tell `fread` to read one byte less than now and then explicitly set the null byte? Like: `fread( ..., (sizeof(my_buffer)/sizeof(my_buffer[0]))-1,...); my_buffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = '\0'`

Comment: Since `fread()` is for reading arbitrary binary data, having it change anything that was read by null terminating it would be a major embarrassment.  Yes, reading one fewer bytes and forcibly null terminating the string would be safe and sane.  See also the update to my answer (`printf("%.*s"...)` part).

Comment: I'll try your suggestions tonight! And thanks for your clear explanations.

Comment: Done! Sorry for the waiting! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In every case, the garbage starts after the 5th bit, as should be expected since `#define BUFFER_SIZE 5`.  If after you read in the value, a '\0' was used to null terminate the legal length of the string (5), like this:

`my_buffer[strlen(my_buffer)-1]=0;` //or since you know its length, `my_buffer[4]=0;`

That would make the contents of my buffer a legal string.  To actually fix the problem, create my_buffer with more space in the first place, then always terminate with '\0'.